# Too many re-renders on setting state

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code which is causing too many renders.

```
const passAcrossSelectedGame = props => {
    if (props.passedGamesFlag === 1) {
      props.setPassedGamesFlag(0);
      gameDetails = {
        blackKingSquare: '',
        whiteKingSquare: '',
        };

      plyViewed = 0;

      setHistory(game.history());

      const auxGame = new Game();

      gameHistory = [];
      gameHistory.push(auxGame.fen());
      game.history().forEach(move => {
        auxGame.move(move);
        fenHistory.push(auxGame.fen());
      });
    }
  };
  passAcrossSelectedGame(props);
```

I've identified the offending line as  `setHistory(game.history());`

When I comment out that line, I do not get the constant re-rendering. But I need it in there! What solution might be suitable for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your function call modifying the state inside a useEffect hook:

```
const passAcrossSelectedGame = props => {
    if (props.passedGamesFlag === 1) {
      props.setPassedGamesFlag(0);
      gameDetails = {
        blackKingSquare: '',
        whiteKingSquare: '',
        };

      plyViewed = 0;

      setHistory(game.history());

      const auxGame = new Game();

      gameHistory = [];
      gameHistory.push(auxGame.fen());
      game.history().forEach(move => {
        auxGame.move(move);
        fenHistory.push(auxGame.fen());
      });
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
  passAcrossSelectedGame(props);
}, [props]
```

You get this error because setState triggers a rerender, that calls again the setState. Thus creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Hey, that worked a treat! I would have never thought the solution would be with the line calling the function. Thanks.